# Multiselect picklist Input Field on Internet Explorer 8

Tags: visualforce, internet-explorer

I have a input field that is multiselect picklist , on chrome it shows two arrows to add and remove values to Chosen side (right side) but in internet explorer doesn't shows these buttons

Google chrome

[image]

internet explorer 8 :

[image]

I tried to apply

> Apexpages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('X-UA-Compatible',
>   'IE=Edge');

and

> doctype="html-5.0"

but these doesn't work. Any ideas what is the issue here? or this is a bug/compatibility issue.

Comment: Is this in a VisualForce page or standard layout?

Comment: This is visualforce page.

Comment: Providing a code snippet of your VisualForce page may help people figure out your issue. Thanks

Comment: This is a simple input field on visualforce page <apex:inputField value="{!idea1.Categories}"  />